# Visual Studio Premium 2013 debug window not showing up at all

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I haven't used my VS in few months, but today I got the need to. So I wrote some code, pressed F5 to see if it compiles and works properly, it started showing compiling process in the bottom window, at the very bottom a Build Successful message shows up, and nothing. The app doesn't start up, I can't click anything in VS (isn't considered as "not responding" by windows), and Task Manager shows three processes named like my app, all having 112K memory usage. After I kill VS process, one of them closes, but I absolutely can't get rid of remaining two, until I restart my PC. Trying to run the exe in project directory also didn't work.

I'm reinstalling Visual Studio to see if it gets fixed from just doing that, but ideas on how to fix it are still welcome in case it doesn't.

Comment: Reinstalling is overrated.

Comment: What kind of application did you write? WinForms, WPF, Console, Web App etc?

Comment: it was a win32 console app

Comment: Oh, that might be it. I remember having issues with avast and VS at some point.